Parts of .obj missing in visualizer
I am trying to import some mesh files just for the sake of visualization in our URDFs, but can't seem to get it to work no matter what I do. I have the models exported as .obj/.mtl, and these work perfectly fine when using online model viewers. When I try to reference them in my URDF and visualize them in Drake, small parts of the model don't get displayed. In this image, there is supposed to be a component that the screws are in, but it just doesn't load. This is how the model is supposed to look, as seen on 3dviewer.net.
I also tried converting the .obj/.mtl files into a .gtlf using a number of options, but they seem to lose all material properties when I do that. All parts of the model display appropriately, but they all have the same material.
This is the full extent of the code I am running:
from pydrake.all import ModelVisualizer, PackageMap, StartMeshcat

meshcat = StartMeshcat()
visualizer = ModelVisualizer(meshcat=meshcat)
visualizer.AddModels("URDFs/test.urdf")

visualizer.Run()
meshcat.DeleteAddedControls()


This is clearly an issue of the .obj contents. Without being able to see those contents, it's almost impossible to give a diagnosis.

@SeanCurtis I am not sure if there is a better way to share it, but I uploaded it to google drive here.
That being said, I don't understand how the problem would be with the .obj when I can go to 3dviewer.net and it loads the model perfectly fine. I updated the original post to include an image of the model as I see it online.

obj is an incredibly non-standard standard. It's very old and its creator has long since disappeared from the landscape. That means that every tool that consumes an .obj file can implement a wide number of arbitrary assumptions and defaults. So, what one loader may find acceptable, another may reject.

I've had the chance to download your .obj. I was able to visualize it just fine (I used model_visualizer and Blender and both showed the same thing. Your link did not include the .mtl file and I wonder if that contributed to your visualization problem.  But, so far, I can't reproduce your reported problem.

@SeanCurtis You were right, the materials were the problem. Apparently the body that was disappearing somehow got assigned two different materials in the .obj. I'm assuming the online viewers I was using just picked one of them to display, but in Drake it didn't display it at all. Thanks for the help!

The issue was that the body not appearing was somehow assigned multiple materials. I fixed this by uploading the file to 3dviewer.net, sorting by materials, then looking through the meshes that had those materials applied. I was able to manually edit the .obj to remove the duplicated portions.

Huzzah! Congrats.
